# I can't communicate between an pyOpenGL canvas and a button on a wxpanel...I'm not sure how to bind the events.

Tags: python, wxpython, panel, python-2.7, pyopengl

I actually borrowed the bulk of this from user 'Fenikso': adding wxGLCanvas to wxPanel problem

I added a simple function to test communication between the wxpanel and the openGL canvas. It works....until I try to communicate from the panel button to the canvas. :P First, i can't communicate with the canvas from the panel. The function bound to the button is failing to update the position of the sphere. Second, it lags horribly. I'm going to try slowing down the function that controls the animation but I was wondering if there is anything I should be doing diff. to speed this up a bit?

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from wx.glcanvas import GLCanvas
import wx


class myGLCanvas(GLCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        GLCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnResize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnRightUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouse)

        self.init = False
        self.width, self.height = self.GetSize()

        self.alpha = 0
        self.beta = 0
        self.distance = 5.0

        self.oldX = 0
        self.oldY = 0
        self.leftDown = False
        self.rightDown = False
        self.axes = False


    def Axes(self, allow):
        self.axes = allow


    def OnDraw(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, (0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0))
        glutSolidSphere(0.5, 20, 20)

        if self.axes:
            self.ShowAxes()

        self.SwapBuffers()


    def ChangeView(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -self.distance)
        glRotate(-90, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glRotate(-90, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        glRotate(self.alpha, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glRotate(self.beta, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        self.OnDraw()


    def Resize(self):
        ratio = float(self.width) / self.height;

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        gluPerspective(45, ratio, 1, 1000)

        self.ChangeView()


    def OnPaint(self, event):
        wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.SetCurrent()
        if not self.init:
            self.InitGL()
            self.init = True
        self.OnDraw()




    def OnLeftDown(self, event):
        self.oldX, self.oldY = event.GetPosition()
        self.leftDown = True

    def OnRightDown(self, event):
        self.oldX, self.oldY = event.GetPosition()
        self.rightDown = True

    def OnLeftUp(self, event):
        self.leftDown = False

    def OnRightUp(self, event):
        self.rightDown = False

    def OnMouse(self, event):
        if self.leftDown or self.rightDown:
            for i in range(5000):
                X, Y = event.GetPosition()
                if self.rightDown:
                    self.distance += (Y - self.oldY) * 0.05

                if self.leftDown:
                    self.alpha += (X - self.oldX) * 0.5
                    self.beta += (Y - self.oldY) * 0.5

                self.ChangeView()
                self.oldX, self.oldY = X, Y



    def OnResize(self, e):
        self.width, self.height = e.GetSize()
        self.Resize()


    def ShowAxes(self):
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)

        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glRasterPos3f(1.2, 0.0, 0.0)
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, ord('x'))
        glRasterPos3f(0.0, 1.2, 0.0)
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, ord('y'))
        glRasterPos3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.2)
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, ord('z'))

        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex3f(1, 0, 0)
        glVertex3f(1, 1, 0)
        glVertex3f(0, 1, 0)
        glEnd()
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 1)
        glVertex3f(0, 1, 1)
        glVertex3f(0, 1, 0)
        glEnd()
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
        glVertex3f(1, 0, 0)
        glVertex3f(1, 0, 1)
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 1)
        glEnd()

        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)


    def InitGL(self):
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE,  (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0))
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT,  (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0))
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glClearDepth(1.0)

        self.Resize()


class ToolPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, canvas, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = canvas

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, label="TEXT 1")
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self, label="Rotate")
        self.check1 = wx.CheckBox(self, label="Show Axes")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.Check1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Button2_Evt, self.button2)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button1, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button2, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.check1)

        self.border = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.border.Add(self.sizer, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, border=5)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.border)

    def Button2_Evt(self, event):
        for i in range(5000):
            X, Y = self.canvas.GetPosition()
            self.canvas.alpha += (X - self.canvas.oldX) * 0.5
            self.canvas.beta += (Y - self.canvas.oldY) * 0.5

            self.canvas.ChangeView()
            self.canvas.oldX, self.canvas.oldY = X, Y
            self.canvas.OnDraw()


    def Check1(self, e):
        self.canvas.Axes(e.Checked())
        self.canvas.OnDraw()

class MainWin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, title='OpenGL', *args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = myGLCanvas(self, size=(640, 480))
        self.panel = ToolPanel(self, canvas=self.canvas)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        self.Show() 


app = wx.App(False)
main_win = MainWin(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm...never mind  The default coords start at 0, 0.  Meaning that since I was using solely multiplication to update the coords, they stayed set at zero. I added +1 to each axis and I'm in business now.